# ionic 3 how to download pdf file from amzon s3 url

Tags: cordova, amazon-s3, ionic3, angular5

I want to download pdf file into device/browser from amazon s3 bucket url in Ionic3.

I have already tried below solution but its not working.

```
Storage.get('test.pdf', { download: true })
    .then(result => {
        console.log(Utf8ArrayToStr(result.Body));
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('error axios');
        console.log(err)
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Install `fileTransfer` cordova plugin using the following command

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
npm install @ionic-native/file-transfer
```

check official [**`doc`**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer)

and install `File` cordova plugin
ionic cordova plugin add cordo

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
npm install @ionic-native/file
```

check official [**`doc`**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file)

and import it in `app.module.ts`

```
import { FileTransfer } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
```

and import those in the `providers` section

```
providers: [
    FileTransfer,
    File,
  ]
```

and then write the following code to download the file

in the constructor

```
  constructor(
    private transfer: FileTransfer,
    private file$: File) { }
```

and download method

```
 download() {
    const url = 'www.amazon.com/sample.pdf' // keep your s3 bucket pdf file url
    const fileName = new Date().toISOString().replace(/[:.]/g, '-'); // mention your file name(here I mention current date and time)
    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
    const dir_name = 'Download/your_project/'; //mention the directory where you want to download in the device
    let path = '';
    const result = this.file$.createDir(this.file$.externalRootDirectory, dir_name, true);
    result.then((resp) => {
      path = resp.toURL();
      console.log(path); //it will give you the path name
      fileTransfer.download(url, path + fileName + '.pdf').then((entry) => {
        console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
      });
    });
  }
}
```

hope it will solve your problem !!

Comment: ok thanks! i will check this solution for device but how about web browser ?

Comment: in the browser, Cordova plugins are going support. You to check for other solutions